# C++ Multi-threading performance of independent data

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

Let's have a very simple C++ class with only a single data member:

```
class Container {
public:
    std::vector<Element> elements;
    Container(int elemCount);
};
```

Now create N threads which do a very simple task:

1. create a local Container with a certain vector size
2. loop through the vector and simply increment each element's val
3. Repeat Step 2 10.000 times (to get times in seconds instead of ms)

The complete code listing can be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q7tRE8AT)

According to [CoreInfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) my CPU (Intel Core i5 2400) has 4 cores and each of them has its own L1/L2 caches:

```
Logical to Physical Processor Map:
*---  Physical Processor 0
-*--  Physical Processor 1
--*-  Physical Processor 2

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
*---  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
*---  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
*---  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
-*--  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
-*--  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
-*--  Unified Cache       1, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--*-  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--*-  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--*-  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
---*  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
---*  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
---*  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
****  Unified Cache       4, Level 3,    6 MB, Assoc  12, LineSize  64
---*  Physical Processor 3
```

For vector size up to 100.000 elements the timings are exactly as expected:

```
Elements count: 100.000

Threads: 1
loops: 10000 ms: 650

Threads: 4
loops: 2500 ms: 168
loops: 2500 ms: 169
loops: 2500 ms: 169
loops: 2500 ms: 171
```

However, for bigger vector sizes the performance of multiple cores is:

```
Elements count: 300.000

Threads: 1
loops: 10000 ms: 1968

Threads: 4
loops: 2500 ms: 3817
loops: 2500 ms: 3864
loops: 2500 ms: 3927
loops: 2500 ms: 4008
```

My questions:

1. Can someone explain the reason of this to me, please? Is this false sharing? If so, how is this possible if threads do **NOT** share any data and all cores have their own L1/L2 caches and cache lines??
2. Is it possible to achieve (or come near to) a linear speed-up efficiency when processing **independent data** in multiple threads?

EDIT: Thanks to all answers, so far. Regarding your questions:

@user2079303: Element contains only a single double data memeber. sizeof(Element)=8. Please see [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q7tRE8AT) for complete source code.

@bku_drytt: resize() is correct. My intention is to create a vector containing elemCount elements in each thread (regardless their initial value).

@Jorge González Lorenzo: You are absolutely correct with the shared L3 cache. I performed another set of tests, single thread only:

```
Elements count: 50.000
Threads: 1
loops: 50000 ms: 1615

Elements count: 200.000 (4 times bigger)
Threads: 1
loops: 50000 ms: 1615 (slightly more than 4 time bigger)

Elements count: 800.000 (even 4 times bigger)
Threads: 1
loops: 50000 ms: 42181 (MUCH more than 4 time bigger)
```

Comment: How big is `Element`? Did you remember to compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Are you purposely calling `resize()` in your constructor instead of `reserve()`?

Comment: My guess is that you are filling the L3 shared cache by using 4 threads (x4 storage needed as there is one vector per thread), and so causing many cache misses, whereas in the single thread execution the vector fits in it. L1 and L2 are per core, but L3 is not. A fair comparison would be to run the single thread execution using a x4 bigger vector compared to the 4 threads execution.

Comment: Your CPU has 6 MB  L3 cache. 100k * 8byte = 0.76MB. Times 4 that is 3 MB. Three times that (300k elements) is 9 MB which doesn't fit into the L3 cache. Getting linear speedup when you're bandwidth limited is by definition impossible, but then if you were actually doing real work this would look different. The problem is that all your "work" is easily masked by a single cache miss (and you will have 10k * 4 more than in the single threaded version)

Comment: @Voo: This really seems to be THE answer. In my original question I asked for a solution. Is the following assumption correct? 
1) identify the size of shared L2/L3 cache
2) determine a reasonable amount of Elements fitting into the cache (multiplied by number of threads minus some reserve, of course)
3) perform calculation in multiple threads
4) if there are more Elements to process, repeat from Step 2

Comment: It really depends on your actual problem and access patterns. There is no silver bullet that will work for every access pattern (you might want to look up cache oblivious algorithms though, those are pretty cool if it fits your algorithm). And if you're really just bandwidth limited no clever playing around with threads will ever change that fact.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the L3 shared cache by using 4 threads (x4 storage needed as there is one vector per thread), and so causing many cache misses, whereas in the single thread execution the vector fits in it. L1 and L2 are per core, but L3 is not. A fair comparison would be to run the single thread execution using a x4 bigger vector compared to the 4 threads execution.